# Openbravo ERP is Open source erp?

Tags: licensing, open-source-definition

I want to deploy Openbravo erp in some companies, but I am confused about it. That ERP software opensource or licencee.

Comment: What license is it under? What makes you think it would either be open source or not?

Comment: @Martijn I want to Openbravo ERP is fully open source or not..

Comment: [This may be off-topic](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/176/do-we-want-to-allow-question-about-specific-open-source-products), since questions asking about specific products generally aren't within our scope.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because under [my suggested policy for license identification questions](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/a/669/190) need to present clear claims of a project's license. The way you have phrased this question makes it sound like you are just curious. I think that for these questions to be constructive, like on Skeptics.SE, we must deal with notable claims.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while I disagree on the full phrasing of curiousdanii's proposal, I agree that there should *at least* be *some* indication why there would be doubt over the open-sourcyness of something before we can answer the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about specific products are generally out of scope

Answer (score 0):

There are three editions, Openbravo Professional Edition (paid edition, commercial features), Openbravo Enterprise Edition  (paid edition,  commercial features, full support) and a Community Edition exists for free, with a limited set of capabilities available and without professional support.